Dependency Conflict with Soroban SDK in Rust Supply Chain Project
Project Overview: I am developing a supply chain project on the Stellar blockchain, focusing on verifying product authenticity through smart contracts. The core tech stack includes Soroban for smart contracts (written in Rust), React for the frontend, Node.js for the backend, and both PostgreSQL and IPFS for data storage. The goal is to create an application where product information is hashed, stored on IPFS, and verified on the Stellar network using Soroban smart contracts.
Issues Encountered:
Soroban CLI Installation Conflicts:
While attempting to install soroban-cli using Cargo, I encountered dependency conflicts, specifically with the syn crate. The error message indicates a version conflict in syn between futures-macro and soroban-builtin-sdk-macros.
The error persists even when using the --force flag with Cargo, likely due to an outdated or incompatible dependency within soroban-cli or its sub-dependencies.
Soroban SDK Storage API Changes:
The Soroban SDK’s recent updates have modified storage APIs, making certain previously available methods (e.g., env.storage().set and env.storage().get) private.
This change has led to compilation errors in my smart contract code, as I rely on these methods to store and retrieve hashed product data within the contract.
Frontend (React) Installation Issues:
While setting up the React frontend, I encountered several package-related errors and deprecation warnings with npm and yarn, leading to incomplete installation.
The installation issues may stem from a mix of outdated dependencies and potential caching conflicts, preventing the successful creation of the React app.
General Development Environment:
I have set up Rust and Cargo successfully, but I’m running into compatibility issues between various tool versions, especially with soroban-cli and the Rust ecosystem.
Additionally, IPFS integration is planned for later but hasn't been set up yet, as I need to resolve the foundational Soroban and frontend issues first.
I’m building a supply chain project on the Stellar blockchain with Soroban smart contracts (Rust), aiming to verify product authenticity. My setup includes Soroban CLI, React for the frontend, Node.js for the backend, and PostgreSQL/IPFS for data storage.
What I Tried:
Soroban CLI Installation: Attempted to install soroban-cli via Cargo. Expected it to install cleanly, but encountered dependency conflicts, specifically with the syn crate version.
React Setup: Tried setting up a React frontend with both npm and yarn. Expected React to initialize without issues, but faced multiple dependency errors and deprecation warnings that prevented successful installation.
Soroban SDK Storage API: Encountered issues with private methods in the latest Soroban SDK version, which broke my smart contract code that relies on env.storage().set and env.storage().get for storing data.
Environment Troubleshooting: Cleared cache, reinstalled dependencies with the --force flag, and even tried uninstalling/reinstalling conflicting packages, but the issues persist.
Expected Result: I expected Soroban CLI and SDK to install correctly, allowing me to work on smart contracts without version conflicts. I also expected a straightforward React setup for the frontend without dependency errors.
Any guidance on resolving these version conflicts and setup issues would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
